# URL for archive of custom post type with 2 taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, urls

I need to generate the URL of an archive page of custom post types with terms from 2 different taxonomies.

The post type slug is "technologies", and the 2 taxonomies of this post type are "applications" and "industries".

I have tried, for example:
/technologies/?applications=processing&industries=food

But this does not return the expected result.

I have not written any rewrite rules as I was expecting wordpress could handle this natively.

Can anyone provide the correct URL syntax for what I need?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, which for future reference was:

/industries/food/?applications=processing